# Turn off deprecated errors in PHP 5.3

Tags: php, wordpress, deprecation-warning

My server is running PHP 5.3 and my WordPress install is spitting these errors out on me, causing my session_start() to break.

```
Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /home//public_html/hub/wp-settings.php on line 647

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /home//public_html/hub/wp-settings.php on line 662

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /home//public_html/hub/wp-settings.php on line 669

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /home//public_html/hub/wp-settings.php on line 676

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /home//public_html/hub/wp-settings.php on line 712
```

This is annoying, but I do not want to turn off on screen error reporting. How do I disable these bothersome deprecated warnings?

I am running WordPress 2.9.2.

Comment: Isn't 3.3.1 the current up to date version of wordpress?

Comment: he seems to like an old php with old wordpress

Answer (score 265, accepted):

You can do it in code by calling the following functions.

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);
```

or

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
```

Comment: Thank you Robus, Will this kill any php error reporting as well?

Comment: Nope, the first one basically tells php to show ERROR/WARNING/PARSE/NOTICE errors, the second one tells php to show all but DEPRECATED errors.

Comment: Using PHP 5.5.9 on Ubuntu "error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT" Have no effect.... but, in my example, "@mysql_connect();" do the trick :-(

Comment: @molokoloco you did it wrong twice. First you did not fix a thing. You just silenced it. 2nd, you still using `mysql` which is deprecated. You should at least switch to `mysqli`

Comment: Doesn't work. Is it overwritten somewhere? Where do you put this?

Comment: what's the difference between `E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED` and the `E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED` syntax ?

Comment: @beppe9000 Both remove the `E_DEPRECATED`-bit from the bit mask. The first by XOR-ing the value, the second by AND-ing the opposite of the value.

Comment: Doesn't work. WordPress does not respect. **debug.log** still full of `PHP Deprecated` messages being generated.

Answer (score 35):

To only get those errors that cause the application to stop working, use:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ (E_NOTICE | E_WARNING | E_DEPRECATED));
```

This will stop showing notices, warnings, and deprecated errors.

Answer (score 25):

I needed to adapt this to

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

Answer (score 16):

You have to edit the PHP configuration file. Find the line

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

and replace it with:

`error_reporting = E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED`

If you don't have access to the configuration file you can add this line to the PHP WordPress file (maybe headers.php):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
```

Comment: It's much better to add this to `wp-config.php`.  It's intended to be edited with configuration settings.

Answer (score 14):

I just faced a similar problem where a SEO plugin issued a big number of warnings making my blog disk use exceed the plan limit.

I found out that you **must** include the error_reporting command **after** the wp-settings.php require in the wp-config.php file:

```
   require_once ABSPATH .'wp-settings.php';
   error_reporting( E_ALL ^ ( E_NOTICE | E_WARNING | E_DEPRECATED ) );
```

by doing this no more warnings, notices nor deprecated lines are appended to your error log file!

Tested on WordPress 3.8 but I guess it works for every installation.

Answer (score 12):

All the previous answers are correct. Since no one have hinted out how to turn off all errors in PHP, I would like to mention it here:

```
error_reporting(0); // Turn off warning, deprecated,
                    // notice everything except error
```

Somebody might find it useful...

Answer (score 11):

In file wp-config.php you can find constant WP_DEBUG. Make sure it is set to false.

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

This is for WordPress 3.x.

Answer (score 7):

I tend to use this method

```
$errorlevel=error_reporting();
$errorlevel=error_reporting($errorlevel & ~E_DEPRECATED);
```

In this way I do not turn off accidentally something I need

Comment: That gives you less control. You're assuming that whatever is currently configured is correct. Better to set it directly as needed so that you don't get overlapping configurations.

Comment: Understand. Every case is different.

Comment: This is nevertheless the best answer. It is the only one that directly answers the question: only disable E_DEPRECATED, without any side effects.

Comment: In fact it should be
$errorlevel=error_reporting(); error_reporting($errorlevel & ~E_DEPRECATED);
but the idea is the best solution.

Comment: @cootje: you're right, the 2nd assignment isn't strictly needed; I've the habit to save in vars new config when changed (and I save old value in a $<configname>_old var of course to be able to restore in a 2nd moment if needed)

Answer (score 3):

If PHP warnings are breaking things in WordPress, but you still want to know what the warnings are, you can disable displaying PHP errors/warnings and only send them to the log file:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
```

Answer (score -4):

this error occur when you change your php version: it's very simple to suppress this error message

To suppress the DEPRECATED Error message, just add below code into your index.php file:

**init_set('display_errors',False);**

Comment: don't do that, that hides all error messages, not only for depreciations.