# Error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document

Tags: php, xml

When I use the below code and parse the xml locally it works fine but when upload the same script at the server it shows error.

Note: I retrieved the `$lng` and `$lat` from the query string and it works fine locally.

```
$lng=$_GET['lng'];
$lat=$_GET['lat'];
$conn=new LoginSystem();
$conn->connect();
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");

$query="select catch_id,catch_details,image from mycatch where longitude='$lng' AND latitude='$lat'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) {
  die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $node = $dom->createElement("mycatch");
  $node = $dom->appendChild($node);
foreach ($row as $fieldname => $fieldvalue) {
      $child = $dom->createElement($fieldname);
    $child = $node->appendChild($child);
    $value = $dom->createTextNode($fieldvalue);
    $value = $child->appendChild($value);
  }
}

$conn->disconnect();
$xml_string = $dom->saveXML();
echo $xml_string;
```

On the server it throws this error. And the document is also empty.....

> This page contains the following errors:
>   error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document
>   Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

Answer (score 42):

I think you are creating a document that looks like this:

```
<mycatch>
    ....
</mycatch>
<mycatch>
    ....
</mycatch>
```

This is not a valid XML document as it has more than one root element.  You must have a single top-level element, as in

```
<mydocument>      
  <mycatch>
      ....
  </mycatch>
  <mycatch>
      ....
  </mycatch>
  ....
</mydocument>
```

Answer (score 7):

The problem is database connection string, one of your MySQL database connection function parameter is not correct ,so there is an error message in the browser output, Just right click output webpage and view html source code you will see error line followed by correct XML output data(file).
I had same problem and the above solution worked perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

You might have output (maybe error/debug output) that precedes your call to

```
header("Content-type: text/xml");
```

Therefore, the content being delivered to the browser is not "xml"... that's what the error message is trying to tell you (at least that was the case for me and I had the same error message as you've described).

Answer (score 3):

On each loop of the result set, you're appending a new root element to the document, creating an XML document like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mycatch>...</mycatch>
<mycatch>...</mycatch>
...
```

An XML document can only have one root element, which is why the error is stating there is "extra content".  Create a single root element and add all the mycatch elements to that:

```
$root = $dom->createElement("root");
$dom->appendChild($root);
// ...
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $node = $dom->createElement("mycatch");
  $root->appendChild($node);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add on to @john-erck 's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11463891/418439, where my issue was due to an external library is using deprecated (since PHP 7.2) `assert(string)` function, which generated extra characters before my xml. The solution for `assert(string)` is to set `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);` ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2803783/418439)) at the external library file.

Answer (score 0):

I Had the same error before but I saw I was using the

```
header('Content-Type: text/html');
```

Please check on your template file if there you are suing the Content Type.