# create xml from mysql data using php

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I have this code:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/xml');

$xmlout = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?>\n";
$xmlout .= "<persons>\n";

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxx','root','');
$stmt = $db->prepare("select * from users");
$stmt->execute();
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    $xmlout .= "\t<person>\n";
    $xmlout .= "\t\t<id>".$row['id']."</id>\n";
    $xmlout .= "\t\t<username>".$row['username']."</username>\n";
    $xmlout .= "\t\t<password>".$row['password']."</password>\n";
    $xmlout .= "\t\t<realname>".$row['realname']."</realname>\n";
    $xmlout .= "\t\t<surname>".$row['surname']."</surname>\n";
    $xmlout .= "\t\t<email>".$row['email']."</email>\n";
    $xmlout .= "\t\t<created>".$row['created']."</created>\n";
    $xmlout .= "\t\t<admin>".$row['admin']."</admin>\n";
    $xmlout .= "\t</person>\n";
}

$xmlout .= "</persons>";
echo $xmlout;
?>
```

and it doesn't work, it have this error:

> error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document
>   Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

Does anybody know, where is problem?

Comment: Remove `?>` or do an `exit;` after the `echo`.

Comment: You shouldn't create XML manually, you should use something like [SimpleXML](http://cz1.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XML Parse Error - Extra content at the end of the document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16972737/xml-parse-error-extra-content-at-the-end-of-the-document)

Comment: I remove ?> or do exit and it doesn't help... And I do this manually because I am beginner in xml and this way seems to me as the easiest way

Comment: Actually XMLWriter is an API for exactly that kind of job. SimpleXML is more for reading simple, small XML structures.

Comment: you can have mysql server do this for you as well https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_xml

Answer (score 0):

What is the `\t` (tab) for? Is there a specific reason you are manually declaring it in the code? Have you tried removing it?

Also, try building the XML string before you set the header, then echo out the string.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to delete, but it's not problem in this

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class instead of string concatenation to build XML. Possibly the special space and tab characters are conflicting with header output. DOM will pretty print output with its `formatOutput` method.

```
header('Content-type: text/xml');

// INITIALIZE DOM OBJECT
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->formatOutput = true;            
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

// CREATE ROOT AND APPEND TO DOCUMENT
$xmlRoot = $dom->createElement("persons");
$xmlRoot = $dom->appendChild($xmlRoot);

// QUERY DATABASE
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxx','root','');
$stmt = $db->prepare("select * from users");
$stmt->execute();

// FETCH ROWS ITERATIVELY
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
     // APPEND PERSON AS CHILD OF ROOT
     $personNode = $xmlRoot->appendChild($dom->createElement('person'));
     // APPEND CHILDREN TO PERSON         
     $personNode->appendChild($dom->createElement('id', $row['id']));
     $personNode->appendChild($dom->createElement('username', $row['username']));
     $personNode->appendChild($dom->createElement('password', $row['password']));
     $personNode->appendChild($dom->createElement('realname', $row['realname']));
     $personNode->appendChild($dom->createElement('surname', $row['surname']));
     $personNode->appendChild($dom->createElement('email', $row['email']));
     $personNode->appendChild($dom->createElement('created', $row['created']));
     $personNode->appendChild($dom->createElement('admin', $row['admin']));
}
$stmt = null; 
$db = null;

// OUTPUT TO SCREEN
echo $dom->saveXML();
```