# PHP simplexml_load_file 2 tags in xml file

Tags: php, xml

I have an xml file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<Job>
    <JobInfo>
        <User>abc</User>
        <Computer>acb</Computer>
        <Started>2018/04/21-21:58:30:0182-06</Started>
        <Ended>2018/04/21-23:10:10:0093-06</Ended>
    </JobInfo>
    <JobFlags>
        <Active>Yes</Active>
        <Complete>Yes</Complete>
    </JobFlags>
</Job>
```

I use `simplexml_load_file` to load file and print out `User`, `Computer` and `Complete` attribute.

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("abc.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
foreach($xml->children() as $xm) { 
echo $xm->User . "<br>";
echo $xm->Computer . "<br>";
echo $xm->Complete . "<br>";
```

But it only print out `User` and `Computer`. The result for `Complete` is empty.
Please help me with this, thank you!

Comment: if you don't want blank lines in your output, try adding an `isset` test before the `echo` e.g. `if isset($xm->User) echo $xm->User . "<br>";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that you are trying to mix the fields from different elements.  You can see from the original XML that `<User>` and `<Computer>` are in the `<JobInfo>` element and `<Complete>` is in the `<JobFlags>` element.  This isn't a problem, but when you use your `foreach` loop, you go through each child element of `<Job>` and output all of the values for each element.  If you change your loop to...

```
foreach($xml->children() as $tag => $xm) {
    echo "element=".$tag . "<br>";
    echo $xm->User . "<br>";
    echo $xm->Computer . "<br>";
    echo $xm->Complete . "<br>";
}
```

You get (please excuse wrong markup, I wanted the layout)...

> element=JobInfo
> abc
> acb
> element=JobFlags
> Yes

If instead you just need those three pieces of information from the document, you could access them using the full path and so just pick out the details your after without using a `foreach`...

```
echo $xml->JobInfo->User . "<br>";
echo $xml->JobInfo->Computer . "<br>";
echo $xml->JobFlags->Complete . "<br>";
```

Gives you.

> abc
> acb
> Yes

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap all elements into a parent tag:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<test>
    <JobInfo>
        <User>abc</User>
        <Computer>acb</Computer>
        <Started>2018/04/21-21:58:30:0182-06</Started>
        <Ended>2018/04/21-23:10:10:0093-06</Ended>
    </JobInfo>
    <JobFlags>
        <Active>Yes</Active>
        <Complete>Yes</Complete>
    </JobFlags>
</test>
```

and then reference in your php:

```
<?php 
$xml=simplexml_load_file("abc.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
echo $xml->JobInfo->User . "<br>";
echo $xml->JobInfo->Computer . "<br>";
echo $xml->JobFlags->Complete . "<br>";
?>
```

It worked here.

I think it's just a matter of making a correct reference to the entire hierarchical structure of the tags.

See this example taken from http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php:

```
<?php 
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<rss> 
    <channel> 
        <item> 
            <title><![CDATA[Tom & Jerry]]></title> 
        </item> 
    </channel> 
</rss>'; 

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml); 

// echo does the casting for you 
echo $xml->channel->item->title; 

// but vardump (or print_r) not! 
var_dump($xml->channel->item->title); 

// so cast the SimpleXML Element to 'string' solve this issue 
var_dump((string) $xml->channel->item->title); 
?> 

Above will output: 

Tom & Jerry 

object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (0) {} 

string(11) "Tom & Jerry"
```

Reference:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/16972780/5074998
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php

Comment: it's in a parent tag `<Job> </Job>`, i just show the part that i work on in the xml file

Answer (score 0):

`simplexml` is a bit *outdated*. Not sure that a `<complete>` tag is valid, xml, it may be the issue.

If you can, try to use **php-dom** instead.
https://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Example to retrieve all the tags texts.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$remote =<<<'EOF'
<JobInfo>
<User>abc</User>
<Computer>acb</Computer>
<Started>2018/04/21-21:58:30:0182-06</Started>
<Ended>2018/04/21-23:10:10:0093-06</Ended>
</JobInfo>
<JobFlags>
<Active>Yes</Active>
<Complete>Yes</Complete>
</JobFlags>

EOF;

$i = 0;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($remote);
foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('*') as $elem) {
    echo $i++.": ".$elem->textContent;
}
```

The package bellong to php-xml:

> Package php-dom is a virtual package provided by:   php7.2-xml

Alternatives: https://php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php

Comment: Can you provide any evidence for this? DOMDocument is for parsing the XML via the DOM API. SimpleXML is up-to-date and, as it's not indicate, is a much simpler library for traversing and creating basic XML (without the overhead of DOMDocument and handling of Nodes, Elements, etc). DOMDocument is great when it is the right tool, but it by no means "newer" or the recommended alternative to SimpleXML.

Comment: Also, there are no "invalid" XML element names that SimpleXML doesn't understand (other than the same basic allowed element names as DOMDocument or an XML parser recognizes, eg a string of numbers, letters and spaces, etc). "Complete" isn't some magic keyword that would throw it off.

Comment: Who use xml anyway:  you? You should let it go now... 1996 school recommendation? lol seriously. «Can you provide any evidence for this? » Yeah: it is 1996 shit, time to evolve and leave php3?

Answer (score 0):

It works just fine for me:

```
abc
acb



Yes
```

You might be confused because you are expecting it all on three consecutive lines. Try outputting it like this instead and it may help you visualize that it is echoing all three of your requested elements (whether they exist or not) for *two* loops (since the XML has two children):

```
foreach($xml->children() as $xm) { 
    echo "Current Element: " . $xm->getName()  . "<br />";
    echo "User: " . $xm->User . "<br />";
    echo "Computer: " . $xm->Computer . "<br />";
    echo "Complete: " . $xm->Complete . "<br />";
}
```

which will output:

```
Current Element: JobInfo
User: abc
Computer: acb
Complete:
Current Element: JobFlags
User:
Computer:
Complete: Yes
```

As Nick suggested in his comment, if you don't want the `<br />` breaks to print when the element doesn't exist, you can use `isset` like:

```
foreach($xml->children() as $xm) { 
    echo isset($xm->User)     ? "{$xm->User}<br />"     : '';
    echo isset($xm->Computer) ? "{$xm->Computer}<br />" : '';
    echo isset($xm->Complete) ? "{$xm->Complete}<br />" : '';
}
```

Or, as NigelRen recommended in their answer, you could skip using `children()` if you know the full path to the elements you need, and just use those paths instead, like:

```
echo $xml->JobInfo->User . "<br />";
echo $xml->JobInfo->Computer . "<br />";
echo $xml->JobFlags->Complete . "<br />";
```

The underlying issue being that when you were echoing out `$xm->Complete` while traversing the `JobInfo` element, it was outputting just the `<br />` because `$xml->JobInfo->Complete` does't exist.