# Can't seem to turn off deprecated errors in php

Tags: php, wordpress, apache2, deprecated

Im on a development server using a version of php that doesn't support `mysql_connect()` our production server does. I have tried: `error_reporting = E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED` but it doesn't work. After restarting Apache I still the deprecated error message.

I have access to the ini file I should not need php functions to change the error reporting. this is also for wordpress.

Comment: you can use mysqli or PDO?

Comment: is WordPress involved at all by any chance?

Comment: yes it is. Hence why I cannot use the mysqli or PDO

Answer (score 1):

error_reporting() is a function. Try: `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED ^ E_USER_DEPRECATED);`. Or `ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED);`. Then test the settings with echo `ini_get("error_reporting");`. Minimal PHP version must be 5.3.0 for that.

Comment: I have access to the php ini file why am I not making these changes here

Comment: Ok, i haven't seen that in original answer. Then in php.ini find error_reporting and change it to error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED. Does it work?

Answer (score 1):

WordPress sets the `error_reporting` to `E_ALL` in its config files, thus overriding whatever you've set in `php.ini`. I beleieve setting `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED)` in `wp-config.php` clears it up. See [Turn off deprecated errors php 5.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803772/turn-off-deprecated-errors-php-5-3) for various and sundry variations on that setting.

Comment: Yep, at first sight it seems that wp-config is loaded after initial settings, but the main changer is `wp-includes/load.php` which is loaded AFTER and has hardcoded settings based on `WP_DEBUG`. So no setting it in wp-config won't do it :/ **you have to edit `wp-includes/load.php`**

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your `mysql_connect()` with `mysqli_connect()`

Comment: Cant wordpress will brak

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you've modified the correct php.ini? Often there are several included with an install. Is this happening on your local development machine, or on a live server? The best way to make sure you've modified the right php.ini is to run a phpinfo file.

Create a new file, name it phpinfo.php and write:

```
<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>
```

Run this script in your browser and go down to the line that says "Loaded Configuration File"

This used to cause me headaches when using a WAMP install.

Comment: One: I hate developing any kind of web app, rails, php or what ever on windows, two: Linux php install comes with one php.ini that I know of and its the one I have been editing all along: /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini, and yes I restart apache after i edit, and refresh the page

Answer (score 0):

setting: `define('WP_DEBUG', false);` to false fixed the issue.