# Turning off Deprecation warnings in PHP.ini file WAMP

Tags: php

I am working on project @ home and using WAMP for development. Currently the `php.ini` file has the following lines set like this:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL &amp; ~E_DEPRECATED
display_errors = On
```

I had hoped in doing so it would prevent deprecation warnings from showing up. However it is not. Is there a way I can adjust `error_reporting` to ignore deprecated warnings.

Output I am getting currently:

[image: Screen of the problem]

Comment: [**Don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. (Also, possible duplicate of [Turn off deprecated errors php 5.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803772/turn-off-deprecated-errors-php-5-3).)

Comment: Do you actually have `&amp;` in your php.ini?

Comment: While code is being converted to MySQLi/PDO, E_DEPRECATED errors can be suppressed by setting error_reporting in php.ini to exclude E_DEPRECATED:

 `error_reporting = E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED`

Comment: btw its not recommended to do so better to use pdo also check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14110189/1723893

Comment: cross-check your php.ini file path from phpinfo() and do it. It should work

Answer (score 36):

You can use this function :

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Or use "@" operator before function name.

```
@mysql_connect();
```

Comment: Thanks, Using PHP 5.5.9 on Ubuntu
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
Have no effect.... but "@mysql_connect();" do the trick

Answer (score 20):

In your php.ini file change the following.. (note wamp has 2 different php.ini files so make the changes on both)

from this

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

to this

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. It turned out however, that I edited wrong `php.ini` file. In my case the correct one was

`C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.25\phpForApache.ini`

and in this file I have changed this line to:

`error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED`.

It didn't make any difference what I had changed in that "obvious" `php.ini` file.

Answer (score 3):

Set your error report to

```
error_reporting (E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);
```

on your php page.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show all errors except deprecated, then use this setting:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED
```

**Edit:** You could also create a custom error handler to hide only `mysql_` deprecation warnings:

```
set_error_handler(function($errno, $errstr) {
    return strpos($errstr, 'mysql_') === 0;
}, E_DEPRECATED);
```

But please note that `mysql_` functions are deprecated. So instead of trying to hide the errors, consider switching to [`mysqli`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: Did you restart the server?

Comment: Yes I did. But it is not working `error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED` is now in `php.ini`

Answer (score 2):

To hide php errors on WAMP server, Please open **php.ini** file and find following line of code

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

and replace it with

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

All errors will be hide/disable.