# Supress all #[\ReturnTypeWillChange]

Tags: php, error-handling, composer-php, deprecation-warning

I am using old library that throw the following error

```
Return type of ... should either be compatible with ..., or #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice
```

My code still works of course, because it isn't really an error and is just a depreciation notice (read: https://php.watch/versions/8.1/ReturnTypeWillChange)

I placed `#[\ReturnTypeWillChange]` in my code and it supressed the error coming from my code. However, the old library i am using still throws this error and i cant find a good way to suppress it. I could place the `#[\ReturnTypeWillChange]` in all necessary place in the code in the library, however the library is mass installed through [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) in a lot of computer, i just cant find a fast way to place `#[\ReturnTypeWillChange]` in all computer !!!

Is there any way to force php to shut up about the `ReturnTypeWillChange` error coming from a specific library ??

Comment: The most obvious is to go to the package maintainer and ask that they update their code, or maybe submit a PR. If they haven’t updated in a while, or aren’t responsive, it might be time to look for an alternative, or fork the repo. Another option is to not upgrade to 8.1 for now. Lastly, you can suppress [depreciation warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2803783/231316), however don’t be surprised if this bites you some day in the future.

Comment: Firstly, don't think of deprecations as something you need to fix *right now*; the entire purpose of them is to give you several years notice that something needs to change. Secondly, "make the message go away" is the wrong attitude; probably most of your code should *not* have the "ReturnTypeWillChange" attribute, it should just be given the correct return type (or left alone until you have time to fix it). Thirdly, *the same applies to library maintainers* - don't hassle them about something that won't actually be a problem for several years.