# PHP Disable Deprecation Warnings for a Single Line

Tags: php, deprecated, deprecation-warning, php-8, php-8.1

I currently have all errors enabled for my site:

```php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

However, in PHP 8.1, some functions are now deprecated:

```
PHP Notice: Function date_sunset() is deprecated in index.php on line 14
```

Due to current requirements, I am unable to update the line to the non-deprecated alternative.

Is there a way to disable error reporting of deprecations just for this single line?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turn off deprecated errors in PHP 5.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803772/turn-off-deprecated-errors-in-php-5-3)

Comment: @Yogendra No, my question asks specifically about turning off deprecated errors only for a single line of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a workaround, you can wrap your deprecated line like this:

```php
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED);
// call_deprecated_function_here()
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Or if you wish to simply toggle the deprecated flag, use this:

```php
error_reporting(error_reporting() ^ E_DEPRECATED); // toggle E_DEPRECATED (off)
// call_deprecated_function_here()
error_reporting(error_reporting() ^ E_DEPRECATED); // toggle E_DEPRECATED (back on)
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting *from PHP 8*, you can add `@` in front of your deprecated function.
With the `@` you suppress the PHP error messages that would otherwise have been thrown at this point; or, more precisely, [quoting the docs' first comment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php):

> the error handler will still be called, but it will be called with an error level of 0

E.g.
`@functionName(...)`

Comment: Dodsn't this also silence higher severity errors?

Comment: @Westy92 no, starting php8.0 the `@` silences all but errors and exceptions

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Answer (score 0):

The proposed workaround is only good until the function is removed, then it will only be fatal at some point whenever the function is removed, and a forced change will be imminent anyway.

Why not try to use what PHP's own API suggests?:

> Relying on this function is highly discouraged. Use date_sun_info() instead.

See [date_sun_info()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-sun-info.php) ... there are less parameters though, depending upon what you may have used previously with **date_sunset**().

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use the newer version because I need the additional flexibility with the additional parameters.