# How to get rid of the Timber deprecated warnings on PHP 8.2?

Tags: timber

I am in the process to upgrade from PHP8.0 to PHP8.2, I currently use the timber/timber package in its 1.22.1 version but it throws a lot of Deprecated warnings, I do not intend to update my Timber to the 2.0 Release Candidate so I was wondering what else can we do to get rid of the warnings.

I tried by updating to the 2.0 Release Candidate hoping it would help fix those deprecated warnings, however it involves a lot of changes since many of the currrent functionalities with 1.x will be deprecated on 2.0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turn off deprecated errors in PHP 5.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803772/turn-off-deprecated-errors-in-php-5-3)

Comment: I do not mean just to hide the warnings but geniunely get rid of them by having clear code, just wondering if the Timber team has the intention to fix it or if it's not priority.

Comment: In that case your question is more appropriate for the Github issue tracker of Timber and not here on Stack Overflow. There are already various similar issues on Github about this - but the general response seems to be that the team prefers to focus on Timber 2.0 and not spend too much time on 1.x anymore (e.g., https://github.com/timber/timber/issues/2548#issuecomment-1081191874, https://github.com/timber/timber/issues/2768#issuecomment-1598294883).

Comment: Of course at some point you would need to upgrade both PHP and Timber to newer versions anyway to get bugfixes and new features, so it is probably best to do the upgrade soon (before you write more code that depends on the old versions, which you would need to change later as well).